# Couldnt install Openstack-Devstack on DigitalOcean

Tags: django, openstack, digital-ocean, devstack, openstack-horizon

I have been trying to install devstack on digitalocean's droplet with ubuntu 14.04 cloud edition. after several times i get this error. is someone familiar with it?[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: this is a terminal output not screenshot of text

Comment: It's a screenshot of a terminal containing nothing but text. You should have copied and pasted the text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably run out of RAM. Try adding swap.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04